# PostgreSQL: How to add element to nested JSON array?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select rooms from users where username='test_user';

**returns** {"roomID":[{"1":"test1"}]}
```

I want to add to`[{"1":"test1"}]` this `{"2": "test2"}` --> `[{"1":"test1"}, {"2": "test2"}]`

My current attempt is this.

```
UPDATE users
SET rooms=(
    (select rooms from users where username='test_user')::json
    -> 'roomID' || '{"2": "test2"}' ::json
)
WHERE username='test_user'
RETURNING *
;
```

Messages
ERROR: operator does not exist: json || json
LINE 4: -> 'roomID' || '{"2": "test2"}' ::json

Comment: im on the latest, wasn't aware those were the version numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_build_object()`:

```sql
update users set
    rooms = jsonb_build_object('roomID', rooms -> 'roomID' || '{"2": "test2"}')
where username = 'test_user'
returning *;
```

or `jsonb_set()`:

```sql
update users set
    rooms = jsonb_set(rooms, '{roomID}', rooms -> 'roomID' || '{"2": "test2"}')
where username = 'test_user'
returning *;
```

Test it in [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f356c9d6f46643533bc7a504b8457c59)

I have assumed the type of the `rooms` columns is `jsonb`. If it is `json` you need to cast the column to `jsonb`, e.g.:

```sql
update users set
    rooms = jsonb_set(rooms::jsonb, '{roomID}', rooms::jsonb -> 'roomID' || '{"2": "test2"}')
where username = 'test_user'
returning *;
```

Note also, that you do not have to use `select` in `update` to get a value of a column, use just the column instead.

Comment: i didn't know you could just use ```room``` instead of ```select```. Thank you. My english is not that great, couldn't undestand a thing how the function's parameters were  working from the docs. ```jsonb_set('param1', 'param2', 'param3' )``` param1 = result, param2 = destructuring, param3 = is destructuring it again ?

Comment: `param2` indicates *the path* to the json object to be modified, `param3` is a new value of this object. Read more in [the docs.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Comment: I think I am gonna stick with jsonb_set() because its much faster.

Comment: That's OK, though there shouldn't be a big difference in performance between the two options. `jsonb_set()` may look more logical.

Answer (score 0):

I turned the json `(select rooms from users where username='test_user')` into jsonb, so I can use jsonb_set() function. Finally added jsonb object`{"2": "test2"} to the destructered the jsonb` [{"1": "test1"}]```

```
UPDATE users
SET rooms=(
    jsonb_set(
        (select rooms from users where username='test_user')::jsonb,
              '{roomID}', 
        (select rooms from users where username='test_user')::jsonb->'roomID'
        || '{"2":"test2"}',
        true
    )
)
WHERE username='test_user'
RETURNING *
```

If anyone knows is there a way to reference a query because `(select rooms from users where username='test_user')::jsonb` is run twice which I think is inefficient (1 sec 362 msec)